# All timer jobs runs three times including my own custom timer job

Tags: 2013, timer-jobs, custom-timer-job

All timer jobs on my server runs exactly three time. Not more not less. I noticed this when I created my own custom timer job. My custom job and all other sharepoint's jobs runs exactly three time. I tried to set `SPJobLockType.ContentDatabase` to `SPJobLockType.Job` but it didn't help. Here is a screenshot that shows the history of the jobs. All runs three time. What should I do at least make mine to run only once?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Is the Server and Web Application rows for each group of 3 the same?

Comment: how many web application, Content Database and Server in the farm?

Comment: also try one more thing, from central admin > application Management > Manage Content DB....click on the database name and at the bottom of the page select a server where you run the timer jobs. test it now.